# How to prevent a custom MUI TextField from losing focus on rerender

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield, react-state-management

I have customized the mui TextField to accept multicolor text as input.

```
export default function MultiColorTextField(
  props: any,
  inputRef: any,
  subInputRef: any,
  setSubData: any,
  data: any,
  focussedField: any
) {
  props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML.__html = data;
  return (
    <Typography
      ref={inputRef}
      {...props}
      component="div"
      variant="body1"
      contentEditable
      suppressContentEditableWarning
      onInput={(evt: any) => {
        setSubData(evt.target.innerText);
        subInputRef.current.focus();
      }}
      onFocus={() => {
        focussedField.current = props.id;
      }}
    ></Typography>
  );
}
```

Implementation of the multicolorTextField

```
  const [subData, setSubData] = useState("");
      <TextField
        id="id-alarm-msg-subject"
        label={t("AlarmMsgTmp.Create.Subject")}
        variant={"standard"}
        InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
        inputProps={{
          contentEditable: true,
          suppressContentEditableWarning: true,
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {
            __html: alarmMsgTmp.formatMultiColorString(subData),
          } as any,
        }}
        InputProps={{
          inputComponent: forwardRef((props: any, inputRef: any) =>
            MultiColorTextField(
              props,
              inputRef,
              subInputRef,
              setSubData,
              subData,
              focussedField
            )
          ),
          ref: subInputRef,
          sx: {
            "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
              overflow: "auto",
              height: "100px",
            },
          },
        }}
        autoFocus={focussedField.current === "id-alarm-msg-subject"}
        fullWidth
        onKeyDown={(evt: any) => {
          if (evt.which == "13") {
            evt.preventDefault();
          }
        }}
      ></TextField>
```

So my problem is simple. I loose focus on the field on every change of input. I doubting that I'm handling the state bad so the re-render triggered by the state change makes the input field loose its focus. I have also tried to set the autoFocus but it din't help me.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't create component inside another component!** On each render the component (the function) gets new reference and the diffing algorithm unmounts the previous one and mounts the new one.

Move the inner component outside

Comment: Please find the edited code above. Still facing the same issue. Am I doing anything wrong with the usage ref?

Comment: @NIV You are still creating component InputProps.inputComponent inside the component. Never create component inside another component. Move all the inner component ouside.